# Could a no code module injected to memory phenomenon in the process tree of the steam.exe file be suspicious?

Tags: injection, memory

I found a page, which analyzing memory processes (https://analyze.intezer.com/)
After the searches, it didn't find anything harmful, but in the detailed analysis I found a module without code, which is injected into the memory among the processes of steam.exe.

Because of some kind of encryption, the page can't recognize the code, or why is a codeless module always injected into memory between steam.exe processes?[image]

Comment: Welcome to the community. Could you elaborate on what you're afraid of or what's not normal in your opinion?

Comment: @SirMuffington I know that memory injection can be abused, as it can hide from antivirus programs. Why is a module without code injected into memory? Is this completely normal?

Comment: Maybe it's a bug in the web app?